# Tightly fitting smaller inline-block divs around a larger one that is floated left

Tags: html, css

Everything was going great until I attempted to text-align:center; my divs. Apparently divs that are floated left ignore text-align but the floated div needs to be that way to have two of the smaller divs on the same line as it.

It's hard to explain but here is an example of the code to describe it better:

https://jsfiddle.net/8fu5b9td/3/

```
.featured-series {
    width:606px;
    height:406px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

All I want to know is how to make the featured-series div act like the standard-series divs and centre itself at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fudging it with a little bit of JS. I know it's naughty but it does the job and it's fairly cheap on resources.

```
function centerContent(){
    $('.center-content').width( Math.floor($('.body').width()/306)*306 );
}

setInterval( centerContent, 250);
```

.center-content has margin:0 auto; and it is the container for all of the series divs. I found that because I couldn't set the width, I really couldn't do much so I have JS set the width to the best possible fit depending on the screen size.

Not the cleanest solution and I'd much prefer pure JS but if it works, it works.

Edit: The .body class is an div which loads ajax inside of it, when it changes size it's basically like the  changing size on a normal page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left;` and add `margin:0 auto;` to it.

```
.featured-series {
    width:606px;
    height:406px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: If I remove float the standard-series divs will not stack on top of each other.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding, the standard-series divs to the direct right of the featured-series div must stack as well. Exactly how I had the standard-series divs in the original one. Just to make sure, are you on a small screen? It might not be immediately obvious as to what's going on on a smaller screen. (With your code changes the featured-series is in the right position but it also moves the standard-series divs out of position, my question is basically, how do I have both).

Comment: I understand now what you want to achieve. Let me edit the jsfiddle

Comment: That's the effect I want to achieve, yes, unfortunately I can't really have set widths as I want it to take up as much of the screen as possible. Is it possible to make header-series not have a set pixel width and just set its width to whatever will fit on the screen but is the minimum width leaving no white space on either side?

Comment: For what you want to achieve I would suggest using Bootstrap framework. It will make your life much more easier...

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/8fu5b9td/7/

CSS

```
@media(max-width: 930px) {
    .featured-series {
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 610px) {
    .featured-series {
         background-color: black;
        display: block;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 300px;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great for mobile but unfortunately it doesn't answer the question as the problem still exists for pages above 930px.

Comment: You want it to be aligned with divs underneath?

Comment: It needs two rows of the standard-series divs to the immediate right of the featured-series div and then the rest go directly underneath. It's possible, as the other poster showed, to do this using fixed pixel widths but it needs to be able to expand, must be dynamic.